# How can I obtain a value in one column based on another column in excel?

Tags: excel

Suppose I have two columns; A and B. each of which has 50 rows of data. I want to set the value of a third column, C, to the value of A corresponding to, say, the minimum value of B. Can I do this without writing a macro?

https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-7978d7e50a58000fc152952a980c09e3?convert_to_webp=true

Answer (score 3):

Consider in **C1**:

```
=IF(B1=MIN(B:B),A1,"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

As you see, no macro is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique values in `Column B` i.e. there's only one minimum value in the column, you can use following formula. Enter this formula in `Cell C1`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(B:B),B:B,0))
```

Or if you have a fixed range say till row 25, use following formula and change number of rows as required:

```
=INDEX(A1:A25,MATCH(MIN(B1:B25),B1:B25,0))
```

[image]

If you've repeating minimum value in `Column B` i.e. minimum value occurs more than one then try this array formula. Enter the formula in `Cell C1` and drag it down till the row you want:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$25, MIN(B:B))>=ROWS($A$1:A1),INDEX($A$1:$A$25, SMALL(IF(MIN(B:B)=$B$1:$B$25, ROW($B$1:$B$25)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$25))+1, ""), ROW(A1))), "")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Again if you want to use this formula for fixed rows say 25 then use following formula. Change number of rows as accordingly:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B, MIN(B:B))>=ROWS($A$1:A1),INDEX(A:A, SMALL(IF(MIN(B:B)=B:B, ROW(B:B)-MIN(ROW(B:B))+1, ""), ROW(A1))), "")
```

[image]

Got the tips for array formula from [here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/01/31/using-array-formula-to-look-up-multiple-values-in-a-list/).